# How many carbon, hydrogen, oxygen, nitrogen, and phosphorus atoms are there in the observable universe?

Tags: atoms, elements, astrochemistry

If I could somehow reliably count all the carbon, nitrogen, hydrogen, oxygen, and phosphorus atoms in the observable universe, what number would I come up with?

Comment: A big one, that's for sure. Phosphate is not an atom. Other than that, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements#Universe

Comment: Nobody knows. Every number estimate will be a conjecture about the unknown worlds. Where does the universe start and where does it end? And who will define the entire universe?

Comment: @achem Astronomers. Whose job is partly observing how much stuff there is and what it is made of.

Comment: Yes but astronomers/astrochemists are as human as they can be. They are intelligent but nobody is yet good enough to know everything about "the entire universe." We do not know "everything" about the Earth and Sun, let alone the universe.

Comment: @AChem It isn't about knowing *everything*, it is about using actual observations to make a reasonable estimate. Yhey don't, for example, need to know everything about the sun to estimate its mass and composition very reliably.

Comment: If you could somehow reliably predict when the first nuclear fusion plant goes to production, what year will it be? // You contradict yourself in the single sentence. As the answer assumes it can done.

Comment: I changed this pesky "entire" as it indeed pretty much disqualified the question. Answer tells about *observable* universe and that's what question should ask (also no "phosphate atoms" in body...) If a user wants to answer a question, that is having serious issues, it should be fixed quickly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two key numbers can be estimated from known observable things in astronomy (and cosmology where current big bang models explain the processes that created the "light" elements and their abundance and observations broadly agree with theory). Spectroscopy allow astronomers to estimate the abundance of many elements in stars and galaxies.

There are also some estimates of how many nuclei there are (based on estimates of the mass of the observable universe.

We can combine the estimates about the number of nuclei with their relative abundance to give some approximate counts for elements.

The number of nuclei [is estimated to be](https://www.universetoday.com/36302/atoms-in-the-universe/) between $\pu{10^78}$ and $\pu{10^82}$ (which are both crazy big numbers though the upper estimate is 10,000 times the lower estimate so don't expect precision).

But we also understand the relative abundance, though most estimates count mass proportion (counting nucleons not atoms). Using [the numbers in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements) and adjusting the estimates for the mass of each elemental nucleus gives the following proportions:

H 92% 
He 7.5% 
O 0.08% 
C 0.05% 
N 0.01%

If we take the mid estimate of total nuclei as $\pu{10^80}$ then there are approximately $\pu{8E76}$ oxygen atoms, $\pu{5E76}$ carbon atoms and $\pu{1E76}$ nitrogen atoms in the observable universe (if I've done my maths right).

Comment: I think the number just changed, so you have to update it. Like the joke of dinosaurs going extinct 65 million and 5 years ago.

Comment: I gave the error bars of a factor of 10^4. Did it change by more than that? ;-)

Comment: Mid? Pretty sure the halfway point between those two estimates is still something like  $5 \times 10^{81}$ :)

Comment: @chepner I good point. I'm thinking logarithmically, as an astronomer probably would.

Comment: And yet, apparently the average density is only [one proton every couple cubic meters](https://wmap.gsfc.nasa.gov/universe/uni_matter.html).

Comment: Also, I feel the urge to mention one googol -- more than everything.

Comment: All these estimated numbers are a figment of human imagination. It is very audacious to even estimate the mass of observable universe. Should we start believing random websites and Wikipedia?

Comment: Even ChatGPT answered that "The mass of the observable universe is not an exact number and is hard to estimate. Different methods and data sources can produce different results. According to recent observations and measurements, it is estimated that the observable universe contains about 10^52 kg of matter. However, it is important to keep in mind that this is an estimate and there are many unknown factors that could affect the accuracy of this number. It's also important to note that this number only account for the observable universe, the actual universe could be much more massive."

Comment: @AChem 10^52 kg of hydrogen would be 6 * 10^78 hydrogen atoms. This is about the same as matt mentioned

Comment: @AChem There is a whole science called astronomy. It has a great deal of actual observational evidence and theory behind it. It is not merely "human imagination". And it has some basis for making estimates about the size of the actual universe. Those estimates have big uncertainties, but they are not imaginary or entirely speculative but are based on actual observations. and the actual numbers are not just random website guesses, but based on actual science.

Comment: @AChem Also, chat GPT does not make good judgements: it merely aggregates internet text without intelligent assessment. So the last sentence is not a sound basis for judging what the science of astronomy actually thinks.

Comment: You might like Feynman's essay (http://www.feynman.com/science/what-is-science)/, as Feynman wrote "Science is the belief in the ignorance of experts." The only point I was trying to convey was that there is no way to prove or disprove the accuracy numbers of such a massive system. Very little is known about it and little knowledge is dangerous to make big claims. Perhaps an advanced alien from a different galaxy can confirm those numbers. Ignore ChatGPT's satire.